# Event click with JavaScript or jQuery in element SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm creating a web application using SVG, but I have a problem:
I need to put an event click on each element comprising the SVG using jQuery. The problem arises when I try to execute the event; it is as if the element is constructed only by points and the event is very unstable. My code is as follows...

```
<figure id="'+id+'" cod="'+cod+'" class="contentOneDent">
<div class="textDent headDent">'+id+'</div>
    <svg class="figureDent" viewBox="0 0 6598 10423">
     <g id="Capa_x0020_1">
      <path     cod="'+ZONE_C_VESTIBULAR_S+'" class="faceDent dent1 CervicalVestibularS" d="M1113 2675c-314,-318 -631,-637 -958,-958 1118,-2319 5691,-2126 6257,-42l-908 1018c-580,-562 -1354,-906 -2205,-906 -841,0 -1608,336 -2186,888z"/>
      <ellipse  cod="'+ZONE_OCLUSAL+'" class="faceDent dent1 Oclusal" cx="3299" cy="5214" rx="1370" ry="1443"/>
      <path     cod="'+ZONE_C_VESTIBULAR_I+'" class="faceDent dent1 CervicalVestibularI" d="M1111 7751c-314,317 -630,634 -956,955 1118,2319 5691,2126 6257,42l-906 -1016c-580,564 -1355,909 -2207,909 -843,0 -1610,-337 -2188,-890z"/>
      <path     cod="'+ZONE_PALATINA+'" class="faceDent dent1 Palatina" d="M2487 6371c-472,463 -922,921 -1376,1380 578,553 1345,890 2188,890 852,0 1627,-345 2207,-909l-1293 -1450c-465,404 -1156,510 -1726,89z"/>
      <path     cod="'+ZONE_MESIAL+'" class="faceDent dent1 Mesial" d="M2484 6374c-471,462 -920,919 -1373,1377 -655,-627 -1066,-1532 -1066,-2537 0,-1008 413,-1914 1071,-2541l-3 2c454,457 903,914 1374,1377l2 -2c-339,263 -560,686 -560,1164 0,475 218,897 555,1160z"/>
      <path     cod="'+ZONE_DISTAL+'" class="faceDent dent1 Distal" d="M5504 2693c645,626 1049,1524 1049,2521 0,995 -403,1892 -1047,2518l-1290 -1447c278,-264 453,-646 453,-1071 0,-427 -176,-810 -455,-1074l1290 -1447z"/>
      <path     cod="'+ZONE_VESTIBULAR+'" class="faceDent dent1 Vestibular" d="M3299 1787c851,0 1625,344 2205,906l-1291 1448c-465,-405 -1156,-510 -1726,-89 -471,-463 -920,-920 -1374,-1377 578,-552 1345,-888 2186,-888z"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
<figcaption class="textDent footDent"></figcaption>
</figure>
```

I need to execute a function when I click in the elements with class faceDent.

Does anyone know how I can implement the event correctly?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please include the relevant code (i.e., the code you're using to add an event handler) in the question itself. You can use Stack Snippets (the button that looks like a page with angle brackets) to organize your code in a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically generated html, you can use .on() to trigger events. Assuming you are adding the dynamically generated html to a div with id "dynamicDiv", then the script goes like :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dynamicDiv").on("click", ".faceDent", function(){
            // your code goes here
            // $(".faceDent ").attr("fill", "red");
        });
    });
</script>
```

P.S. If you are generating the html dynamically in angular js, then you should consider compiling it exclusively.

Documentation for $compile : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: hello, I try this way, but the event is run incorrectly, sometimes if and some not, you need to click many for the event is triggered.

Comment: are you using angular js ?

Comment: I have made some minor changes in the code, which you can try. It should work fine even with dynamically generated code.

Comment: i don't using Angular, only Jquery.

Comment: Try the code snippet from above and let me know if it worked :) Just change the id of the html div to which you are adding you dynamic html. If you are not using dynamic html, then just use the id of the container div of the svg element. :) Cheers :)

Comment: and I tried it, the same thing happens with $('.faceDent'). on('click')

Comment: Try   $(document).on("click", ".faceDent", function(){
            // your code goes here
        });     And please try to explain what's happening and what's going wrong when you try any of the solutions. Better create a jsfiddle so that people can better understand your problem and help you out..

Comment: hello, thanks for helping, excuse me, I'm new to the forum, but I could solve my problem, the error was not in the click event, but was also in the same element  `.faceDent` activated `hover` event, changing the property `fill` to `none`, which caused the surface of the disappeared and therefore was not running the click event, since there was not a surface he were clicking, or at least understand what achievement.

Comment: Hello, your response code was very useful for another procedure needed thanks :D `$("#dynamicDiv").on("click", ".faceDent", function()`. It works perfectly

Comment: Glad to be of help.. :)